# Grant access to "SharePoint Service Administrator" domain group using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, spo

How to grant access to "SharePoint Service Administrator" domain group using PowerShell in SP Online?

It doesn't have a email and i tried with Account ID and name, both didn't work.

Comment: Did you tried the options available here ? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/assign-roles-to-user-accounts-with-office-365-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Use the script below to automatically add user in the domain group -

```
$AdminURL = "https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$AdminName = "user.domain.onmicrosoft.com"
$SiteCollURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/example"
$SiteCollectionAdmin = "mark@crescent.onmicrosoft.com"


$SecurePWD = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" –asplaintext –force 
$Credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $AdminName, $SecurePWD 
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminURL -credential $Credential
Set-SPOUser -site $SiteCollURL -LoginName $SiteCollectionAdmin -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it through PnP Powershell. Below is the PnP powershell script to update "SharePoint Service Administrator" as SCA for all site collections:

```
$credentials=Get-Credential
$URL="https://Company.sharepoint.com"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $URL -Credentials $credentials
$siteColl=Get-PnPTenantSite 
$loginName = "c:0t.c|tenant|ID Of SharePoint Service Administrator domain group in your tenant" 
foreach($site in $siteColl)
{ 
write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Updating SCA for site: " $site.Url  
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url -Credentials $credentials  

$scaColl=Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin   
foreach($sca in $scaColl)  
{          
    Add-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -owners $loginname 
} 
}
```